# How to change the wifi firmware in use

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I'm having instability problems with my wifi, which apparently uses the  iwlwifi driver that people have a lot of problems with.
Looking at the output of `modinfo iwlwifi`, I see (among other things) this list:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-12.ucode
```

However, I downloaded the a firmware from Intel, and I remember that it was **iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode** which I don't see in this list.

I suppose then, that this firmware is not being used. How can I verify this, and how can I make it being used?

**EDIT**
Adding more info. Output of `ls /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260*`

```
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode 
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
```

Output of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`:

```
[    3.022242] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-15.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.022266] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.027457] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.054662] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless N 7260, REV=0x144
[    3.054768] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.055031] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.564903] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.565165] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.756290] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.756555] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

**EDIT:**
Although not a perfect solution as he wifi still breaks some times, the suggestion in the comments of the accepted answer to use v 14 of the firmware, really improved the wifi connection! Now whenever it fails I just use `sudo service network-manager restart` and everything is back to normal!

Comment: You downloaded firmware, not a driver. What did you do with the firmware file?

Comment: I've put it in `/lib/firmware/`. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You probably made some mistake. Please post output of `ls /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260*` to your question.

Comment: And also lets see what firmware has been loaded. Post output of `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`.

Comment: And `13` is not the latest firmware. There is 13,14 and 16 already.

Comment: I am using `16` iwlwifi firmware. It is not shown in modinfo either. That's not a problem.

Comment: I don't really understand how this al connects together :( It's my 2nd day of Ubuntu, and back at Windows this was usually all done for me. I already added the info you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your firmware has been loaded succesfully. You can see it here

```
[    3.027457] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.30.13.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

It is not shown in `modinfo` for some reason but it does not affect anything. Probably the `modinfo` binary should be updated.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and it shows up to `13`. Yours is older and shows up to `12`.

See my output:

```
pilot6@X200MA:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep firmware
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-13.ucode

[   11.883068] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.949453] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 16.242414.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   12.173196] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
```

Comment: I thought I had found the reason for the wifi instability, but seems it's just another dead end. I'll create a question for help on debugging the instability. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I have exactly same wireless adapter. And you I have no problems with it. But I had to update restrictions for my country. Do you have problems on 5 GHz?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 5 GHz but I imagine you're referring to the WiFi band. I just checked my router and the band is 2.4 GHz.

Comment: I have no ideas then. The adapter works perfectly for me. Try 14 firmware https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7260-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz

Comment: Ok, I've added 14, let's see if it holds. One question though, why did you said just the 14 and not the 15 as well? In my output it also says `Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7260-15.ucode failed with error -2`.

Comment: It is OK. Kernel tries to load all firmware from the highest number. The 15 version has never been released. But 16 will not work on your current kernel. For me both 14 and 16 on kernel 4.4 work quite well. May be you have other kind of wireless problems.

Comment: Ok mate, some dayss later the wifi, although it still breaks some times, it's considerably less times than before, so I think it's safe to say your suggestion of using version 14 worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that keep getting wifi disconnects with the Intel 7260 firmware here are the steps I took to get this so the disconnects are not as frequent:

As suggested, version 14 of the firmware seems to be the most stable.
You can get this file from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32885273/iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode).

I actually did a `git clone` of the firmware like so: `git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/linux-firmware.git`

This wasn't as big of repo as I thought it would be. In the linux-firmware directory root are all the current versions for the 7260. From the cloned repo linux-firmware directory (or where you downloaded the file) you can copy the firmware into your local firmware lib like so:

`sudo cp iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode` will copy version 14 of firmware to your firmware directory.

---

You can reboot to restart your wifi with ver 14 of the firmware, or do the following **which can also be used to restart your misbehaving wireless adapter**:

1. `su`  (`sudo` will not work. You need to be `su`)
2. Figure out your wireless device #
   `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`    Output will look something like below. What we are interested in is the device # which in my case is: **0000:08:00.0**

`[3775.484091] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load for     iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode failed with error -2`

3. Run `echo 1 >  /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:08:00.0/remove` but **substitute your device #** where I have 0000:08:00.0

   **IMPORTANT** executing this will kill your wifi connection.
4. Execute `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan`  this will force your system to look for any any PCI devices that may be dead (like the one we killed in step 3).
5. `killall wpa_supplicant`  This may not be necessary, but in my case it is.
6. Use your system's applet or process to reconnect your wireless adapter. You may need to wait 10 or so seconds between commands for this to work.

Before when the wireless went south I had to reboot to restore the wifi. These steps are a royal pain. But it beats waiting for a reboot.